# regex for group of square brackets and comma javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to construct a regular expression which I can use to replace all instances of "],[" with just "," in a string.

I'm stuck on this.

I've been through a number of different combinations - currently trying:

```
str.replace(/(\[,\])/, ',');
```

But it's not picking it up and I can't see what's wrong with it - anything obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You are using the brackets in wrong order and you need to match multiple occurrences with `g`  flag, `.replace(/],\[/g, ',')`. Or, if you want to use a capturing group, `.replace(/](,)\[/g, '$1')`

Comment: You're a gentleman Wiktor, thank you, that works. If you add that as an answer I'll up mark it and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the brackets in wrong order and you need to match multiple occurrences with the `g` flag.

So you may use

```
text = text.replace(/],\[/g, ',')
```

Or, if you want to use a capturing group,

```
text = text.replace(/](,)\[/g, '$1')
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/RwBcfI/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/RwBcfI/2).

**NOTE**: If there may be any amount of whitespace between the brackets, use `\s*` to match it, e.g. `text = text.replace(/]\s*,\s*\[/g, ',')`.

JS demo:

```js
var text = "text],[text2],[text3";
console.log(text.replace(/],\[/g, ','));
console.log(text.replace(/](,)\[/g, '$1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your square brackets are positioned wrongly, and you don't need the normal brackets.

Let's go in steps:

1. You want to replace all intances of `],[` so you need to use the following:

```
/],[/g
```

The `g` in the regexp is ensures that **all** instances  are replaced.

2. `[` and `]` are special characters, so you use `\` to stop regexp from parsing them:

```
/\],\[/g
```

**Final Result:**

```js
let str = '[myString],[AnotherString]';
str = str.replace(/\],\[/g, ",");
console.log(str);
```